# Can these products protect a pc from emp jamming during work?

Tags: pc

My sister's boyfriend lives in a bad neighborhood. He creates graphics on canva. Unfortunately, he is going through hell due to emp jamming. He is looking for a cost efficient and easy to use solution. My sister has asked me whether the following products can be used to protect the work pc from emp jamming while working.

1. https://www.amazon.in/Tufkote-carbon-Twill-Weave-Design-Inches/dp/B013I1IQH6/
2. https://robu.in/product/carbon-fiber-sheet-plate-125mm-75mm-0-5mm/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIv6-S1pnP9wIVkTMrCh3SIQfJEAQYAyABEgJbufD_BwE
3. https://www.amazon.in/carbonblack-composites-Fiberglass-Cloth-White/dp/B07J3QJ84G/
4. https://www.amazon.in/Carbon-Fiber-Tube-Roll-Wrapped/dp/B07X7XGBHX/
5. https://www.amazon.in/LOVIMAG-Conductive-Shielding-Repellent-Electrical/dp/B07C6YLNYL/

Comment: From my rudimentary understanding, if something is nonconductive it will NOT block EM waves. Some carbon fiber products are conductive to varying degrees. Raw fiberglass on the other hand would be utterly useless. Plain old Aluminium foil is a good option. (there's a reason behind tinfoil hats, lol) some Zinc Rich spray paints word pretty well (Yes, the paint itself might be nonconductive when dry, but the individual particles of zinc Are.), as does fine metal (preferably copper) mesh. Google "Faraday Cage"

Comment: lol, one of those products seems to actually be Vinyl, a plastic. Only "5" is likely to be effective.

Comment: Can you maybe **describe what exactly he's experiencing**? 'EMP jamming' combines two separate terms (EMP and (I assume radio) jamming)... An EMP would knock out all electronics definitively in an area, and radio jamming won't affect computer hardware (apart from your wifi connection if it's flooding the right frequency range).

Comment: By the way, if it's the latter, simply using a network cable definitively fixes any WiFi connectivity issues. Ignore the expensive gold plated fads and STP is probably not necessary either, just a regular **UTP cat. 5** cable.